# Expand range on xt FC-M5100-2 cranks

Tags: shimano, cassette

I am wanting to convert Giant toughroad SLR from 2x10 to Di2 2x11.
It has a QR 135MM rear axle and am told it should accept a shimano 11sp cluster, say the CS-M8000 11 46t

The xt cranks are 26 36 which does not have big enough range. My current cranks are FSA v drive 32/44. And this is the preferred range. Can I get alternative chain rings of the 32/44 size or is there a better way to do this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you want to replace the cranks?

Comment: The chainwheels have had some teeth banged off

Comment: Is replacing the rings on the existing crankset ok? You might be out of luck getting 44t ring for the XT

Comment: The best you’ll do is 38 tooth for 96 BCD. There are some 40 tooth rings but seem to be for triples.